# CouchDB JWT Authentication Fails

Tags: jwt, couchdb

[Followed the instructions](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication) on CouchDB.org and configured the CouchDB server. I added the user (the `sub` to the `_security` setting as admin of a particular DB, and when I try and `GET` that document, I'm getting the error:

```
{
  "error": "bad_request",
  "reason": "Not a valid key"
}
```

I know the `public.pem` key is valid and then formatted per instructions (single line w `\n`) prior to be pasted into CouchDB's `.ini` file. The public key comes directly from my Node.js server which issues (and successfully verifies) the JWT's.

My JWT header looks like:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "mykey"
}
```

My `.default.ini` config file on CouchDB looks like:

```
hmac:mykey = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nM...\n
```

Is this a Base64 vs Base64URL issue? I've tried `rsa:mykey` and `HS256.mykey` as well. Any help would be appreciated. The CouchDB debugs are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and working. The JWT Header's `"alg": "HS256"` means symmetric key was used to sign. I was using RSA (asymmetric) keys to sign. Changed `alg` to `RS256` and it worked on the 1st try.